# Sql Azure import to localdb fails with Collation 1033 is not supported

Tags: sql-server, azure, bacpac

I am getting the following error when I try to import data tier application into my local SqlServer.

Could not load schema model from package. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

Collation 1033 is not supported. You must specify one of the supported collations in the Collation attribute. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

I have tried using Sql Server 2012 and 2014.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio and SQL Server twice.  I have managed to successfully import that .bacpac file on a different development server with no problem.  I can't figure out what I'm missing here on my new development server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to fix this.

Add a key “ExtendedLocale” to the registry in the NLS folder. It can be empty.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\ExtendedLocale

After talking with a Microsoft Engineer this had to do with an automatic language pack removal. It was deleting that registry key for some reason. There is no way to stop the automatic language removal.